# How to render html code in strings of a Gatsby config file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I understand how the Gatsby config file parses and interprets markdown files but what I can't seem to figure out is how to parse and interpret inline html within the strings of Gatsby's config file.

To give an example, Victor Zhou does it for his blog for which he also uses Gatsby, you can see in line 6 and 28:
https://github.com/vzhou842/victorzhou.com/blob/master/config.js

I'd like for some string like:

```
author: {
    bio: 'I love <a href="https://google.com/">Google</a>'
}
```

to ultimately render as (where Google is a link to "https://google.com/"):

```
I love Google
```

but right now it just renders as:

```
I love <a href="https://google.com/">Google</a>
```

I imagine the solution is very simple and straightforward, but for some reason, I've been hard stuck on this and it's really bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by sanitizing the html first and then injecting it to the element. 
For example:

```
import sanitize from "sanitize-html"
// For more info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html#what-are-the-default-options

const whereYouWantToSanitize = (props) => {
  const htmlText = "Your <br /> <span class='red'>text</span>"
  const options = {
    allowedTags: ['br', 'span'],
    allowedAttributes: {
      br: ['class']
    }
  } //Check documentation for reference
  return (
    <YourComponentOrElement dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: sanitizeHtml(htmlText, options)
    }} />
  )
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, i don't think this is a matter of sanitizing html. in case i'm misunderstanding something i went ahead and tried what you suggested but it didn't do anything. i think it's a matter of how gatsby takes the config file, parses it, and ultimately interprets it. my gut feeling is that there is some plugin, the same way i would do with webpack. but looking at the gatsby config plugins, they all seem to be focused around the content that's ultimately rendered and the config file rendering seems to be a lot more niche of a problem?

Comment: I tried and it worked for me. Did you correctly set your `options`? Because you may be using some html elements that are not supported by default as well as some attributes and you have to specify them. I will update my answer with some `options` so you can see how it works.